# Need help for RestKit data sync scenario

Tags: ios, objective-c, rest, restkit

I am using RestKit for an iOS To app. I already had done following using restkit:
1. Pull server objects from rest api in json format.
2. Delete orphan objects in core data which are no longer present on server.

Now i have to build the following scenario, if the internet is available on the device and user is adding a new data item,then what should i do first i.e should i store the new data first locally and then post to server or first i post the data to server and the pull it back on device ?

Secondly if the internet is not available on device and user inserts a new data item then saves data locally, On internet availability how do i post newly added data items to the server i.e what approach should i follow and if restkit can help me tackling this scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

RestKit includes reachability monitoring (actually part of AFNetworking). So you can set a block to be run when the status changes:

```
[objectManager.HTTPClient setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:...
```

Generally, store the item locally in all cases. When the item has been pushed to the server, set the sync date or a flag on the item to confirm that it has been updated.

This is really a broader question about how you manage local modifications and updates to the server. You may want an overall scheme to list the `dirty` objects and push updates to the server and have the server response set the sync time for each item. If you use 2 dates (one for the last local modification and one for the remote sync) then a quick predicate fetch on the model will tell you which objects are dirty and need to be pushed to the server.

Comment: Whenever there is RestKit, you will find "Wain" :). Thanks @Wain, i am also developing an offline mode application, your solution is good.