# Auto-recover operations that failed with network issue when network resumes in RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I want to use RestKit in my application, and just read through the ReadMe file. One thing I want to confirm is that, will RestKit auto-recover all operations that failed with network issue when network resumes? If so, how to enable this feature? If not, any suggestion about this feature is welcome

Comment: No, it won't, you need to design a scheme yourself to manage the situation

Comment: Thanks @Wain, could you share more information about how to create/update/delete local objects without network and then how to update the server when network resumes.

Comment: I don't think it's a specific requirement, just want to make sure there is no duplicate work about this feature.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21388797/restkit-0-20-json-mapping-along-with-additional-offline-data and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236009/need-help-for-restkit-data-sync-scenario

Comment: Get it, thank your very much

Answer (score 0):

Just use https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability
It's simple with blocks and works like a charm

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for this question, I'd like to know more about how to update objects in offline mode and how to update the server when network resumes.